# Running Oracle XE Server in VMWare Player

Tags: windows-xp, vmware-player

I have installed the Oracle XE server an VMWare on Windows XP. In the virtual machine environment I have installed Oracle XE server also.

The Oracle server which is running on actual Windows machine is fine, But the Oracle server in the virtual machine is not working properly.

The Oracle Service XE is not listed in the `lsnrctl services` command.

When I'm trying to connect through `sqlplus` it's throwing an `ORA-12514 Error`, and I checked the net and tried all the suggestions, but the problem persists.

Is there any restriction on Oracle XE running in Windows machine and its virtual machine?

The actual machine and the virtual machine both are Windows XP. I have installed Oracle XE server on either of the machines separately.

Comment: Are you trying to run XP+Oracle+VM+Oracle all at the same time? If so, I'm guessing that's the problem. Oracle on the vm might not have enough system resources to start.

Answer (score 0):

Formally, the Oracle XE licence only allows one database running per 'server'. Using virtualization to run multiple XE databases on a single physical server may be interpreted as a licence violation.

Technically, I haven't had problems in running XE on a virtualised server (though I generally use VirtualBox rather than VMWare). And if the machine has enough grunt, there's no technical reason why it can't run on both the guest and host (or in parallel in different guests).

Checklist

1. What is the OS in the virtual machine ?
2. If Windows XP is the guest OS, are both the listener and database services running
3. If Linux is the guest OS, can you see the relevant oracle processes in a `ps`
4. From within the guest OS, can you connect to the database without using the listener (eg a straight `SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA` as the oracle user or administrator)
5. If the database isn't running, look for the alert.log
6. If the database is running, but the listener can't connect, it is probably a network issue

Guest OSs have several options for networking. Host-only, NAT, bridged. They offer different options about what other machines can talk to the guest OS. They can also impact the ip address assigned to the guest OS. If the guest OS is acquiring different IP addresses for each boot/restart that can cause the listener a problem. It expects the IP address to remain constant.

And networking will also determine whether you can see the oracle database on the guest from the host.